# Python discord webhook doesn't really mention role

Tags: python, discord

I have a problem with mentioning role with discord webhook. I'm using discord_webhook library.
When I try to mention a role webhook tags it and it looks fine but it didn't really ping users from that group. The message isn't also highlighted for them. That's not how the group mention should work

In code my mention looks like this:

```
<@&823xxxxxxxxxxx01>
```

But in real webhook:
[webhook](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JR2P7.png)

Do you know how to make the webhook with notification highlithed for specific group? Of course my ping doesn't make classic discord ping sound (or notification)

Comment: Tbh, this sounds like an issue with your bots privileges in your Discord server itself.  If you can click on the tagged group and it's properly resolving, the bot probably just does not have the right to ping that group.

Comment: @tayler6000 I don't think thats a problem with roles. When I send a message without embeds via the same bot it ping the role correctly https://imgur.com/a/CE1a94O

Comment: Interesting.  I think it has to do with how Discord handles embedded messages.  So I don't think it's your code. You could make it just send a separate message with the ping after the embed, but other than that I don't think it can be fixed unless you report it as a glitch to Discord.

Answer (score 0):

**You can not ping someone inside embed message**. You need to **send ping first**, embed then (or embed first and ping seccond).

It's because **discord** is thinking you are doing some kind of **role list** without mentions (like **role shop**)